# Get current position of MPMusicPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmusicplayercontroller

I was wondering how to get the current position of an MPMusicPlayer. For example, if the music player is playing a song and it is currently at 0 minutes 23 seconds, how would I get that value as well as set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below property to get current position

> mpMusicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime

Answer (score 0):

The following links can help you-

[How to set music playback slider in music player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258887/how-to-set-music-playback-slider-in-music-player)

[Problems with currentPlaybackTime and MPMusicPlayerController and iOS 7.1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22540282/problems-with-currentplaybacktime-and-mpmusicplayercontroller-and-ios-7-1)

[Using MPMusicPlayerController, setting musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime to seek but takes second to take effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379165/using-mpmusicplayercontroller-setting-musicplayer-currentplaybacktime-to-seek-b)

https://github.com/gangverk/GVMusicPlayerController